# Formula involving MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with Cost Center (CC) and General Ledger (CC).

```
In column A I have GL's,  
Column B should be CC'ers,  
Column C is the $ value.
```

However, there are certain GL's which apply to 10+ CC'ers so I have created another table with different "lists" which indicate what fraction of the GL's cost should go to different Cost centers. Column E is CC's and Column F,G are different breakdowns of the costs.

So in Column B the user picks "List" number instead of having to pick 10 different CC'ers.

so then I have to calculate the cost for each GL and CC account. Column I is CC and column J is GL and column K is the costs.

```
=SUM(IFERROR((IF($J2=$A$2:$A$7,INDEX($E$1:$G$3,MATCH($I$1,$E$1:$E$3),MATCH($B$2:$B$7,$E$1:$G$1)),FALSE)*OFFSET($B$2:$B$7,,1)),0))
```

The above formula only looks at column B and uses the first match "List 1" and doesn't change lists.

Comment: You want us to magically make MATCH change how it works?  There are other formulas that ***MIGHT*** work for you, but, you have not given us enough information.  Please include test data, expected outcome and a better explanation of what you expect the formula to do.

Comment: Please [edit] the question above with new information.  Please include test data in tabular form with expected output.  Do not clarify in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This array formula will do what you want with the provided data:

```
=SUM(IF(J2=$A$2:$A$7,$C$2:$C$7*INDEX($F$2:$G$3,N(IF(1,MATCH($I$1,$E$2:$E$3,0))),N(IF(1,MATCH($B$2:$B$7,$F$1:$G$1,0))))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you very much for your help. However, it still seems to only use the first column B value. if you change B3 to "List 2" the value should change, I should be 4895*0.3+2866*0.4.. however its still multiplying both values by 0.3